# Java NullPointerException in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

This simple piece of code removes any Statistic in an arrayList if its properties are null.  Unfortunately, I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the first line of the `if Statement (if tempStat.serialName==null...)`.  Thoughts?

```
public static ArrayList<Statistic> removeEmptyStats(ArrayList<Statistic> al) {
    Statistic tempStat=new Statistic();
    for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++) {
        tempStat=al.get(i);
        if (tempStat.serialName==null || tempStat.serialPublisher==null || tempStat.serialISSN==null || tempStat.serialOnlineISSN==null) {
            al.remove(i);
        }
    }
    return al;
}
```

Comment: `tempStat` is `null` then

Comment: @ZouZou Better make that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be because tempStat itself is null. However you need to be very careful with this.

Say you have 5 elements in your list element 2 is invalid so you remove it, element 3 has now dropped back to element 2, but you're going to move on to check element 3 next, however this is now the old element 4 (if that makes any sense!)

Answer (score 2):

You should not remove entries of a list on which you are doing a loop.

`tempstat` is `null`, because when doing `for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++)`, it stores the initial value of al.size().
Then when you are doing `al.get(i)` after having removed some values, you can have a `i` which is higher than the size of the list. (BTW, once you remove a value, it also mean that you will skip one in your list).

You'd to have to use an iterator and iterator.remove().

```
Iterator<Statistic> iterator = al.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Statistic tempStat = iterator.next();
    if (tempStat.serialName==null || tempStat.serialPublisher==null || tempStat.serialISSN==null || tempStat.serialOnlineISSN==null) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need 125 reputation... Reference for that claim? Because I don't think it's accurate.

Comment: What do you mean @rhobincu?

Comment: @YMomb I mean you can very well remove the elements from an array in a for loop, you just need to make sure you decrement the loop counter after each remove. There is no language restriction to prevent you from doing that.

Comment: No language restriction, just a bad practice. It is dirty to use a `for` loop with a counter and to update the counter inside the loop.

Comment: @YMomb There's a big difference between "cannot" and "should not".

Answer (score 1):

The variable tempStat is null! check the values contained in passed array al